# Jenkins: Comment on Bitbucket Pull Request

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, pull-request

Our Jenkins + Bitbucket cloud integration already works and uses a multi-branch pipeline job to notify Bitbucket about the build status of a pull request.

Now I want to enhance it and add preview environments, for example at `pr150.testing.company.com` so that we can test a live production build before merging. I planned on using docker-compose to dynamically start/stop the preview environments.

Now, Jenkins needs to comment the Bitbucket pull request with the link to the preview environment. I know that [the Bitbucket API supports creating pull request comments.](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/pullrequests/%7Bpull_request_id%7D/comments#post)

I imagine comments like this:
[image: A Jenkins pull request comment]

[This example is taken from Jenkins-X](https://jenkins-x.io/docs/build-test-preview/preview/#what-happens-when-a-preview-environment-is-created)

Does any Bitbucket plugin for Jenkins support automatically creating such comments?

Edit: To clarify, a plugin that automatically comments on the pull request would be enough. It's no problem to create the content of the comment on our end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find a plugin but you can execute shell commands as part of the jobs build to do it. Since Jenkins works off commits and not pull requests it's a bit of a faf. You need to get the pull request ID from the branch name using the API first. Using the REST 1.0 API you can do it this way.

```
BranchName=`echo ${GIT_BRANCH} | sed 's/origin\///'`
PullRequestID=`curl -s --request GET --url '{bitbucket_url}/rest/api/1.0/projects/{project_key}/repos/{repo_key}/pull-requests?State=OPEN&at=refs/heads/'${BranchName}'&direction=OUTGOING' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -u username:password | sed -n 's/.*"values":\[{"id":\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p'`
echo '{"text": "Here's my comment with hyperlink"}' > comment.json
curl --request POST --url '{bitbucket_url}/rest/api/1.0/projects/{project_key}/repos/{repo_key}/pull-requests/'$PullRequestID'/comments' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -u username:password -d @comment.json
rm comment.json
```

Notes:

- The remote name might not be origin but something project specific. Check the console log to find it out
- Will need changing for 2.0 API but concept should remain the same